# jQuery Isotope filtering add baguetteBox

Tags: javascript, html, filter, lightbox, baguettebox

I made a Website with a Imagegallery, who is able of beeing filtered with jQuery Isotope.

You can click on the thumbnails and then cycle trough the images with the baguetteBox plugin

[Website](http://duddl123.dothome.co.kr)

Now the thing is, When the Imagegallery is beeing filtered, the baguetteBox plugin still cycles trough all the images. Even the ones who are not showing up when the filter is applied.

I don't know how I could solve this.

---

```
$('.filters ul li').click(function(){
$('.filters ul li').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');

var data = $(this).attr('data-filter');
$grid.isotope({
filter: data
})
});

var $grid = $(".grid").isotope({
itemSelector: ".all",
percentPosition: true,
masonry: {
 columnWidth: ".all"
}
})
```

---

filter : [Check the codepen link here](https://codepen.io/konyali/pen/WZQKwG)

baguetteBox: [Check here](https://demo.tutorialzine.com/2017/02/freebie-4-bootstrap-gallery-templates/)